# Clicking on Like for a certain page results in a Like to the domain

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a `fb:like` tag with `href="http://www.example.com/page.php?id=1"`, and for some reason, and **only for some of the pages**, clicking on like results in liking http://www.example.com.

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meta tag `og:url` would be the one you need to pay attention to, or if you did define data-href, take a look at it in the plugin html5 code.